# Changing content in app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Hi I'm new to android development. I had this question in my mind.
Suppose I wanted to build a app with different tabs and  in each  tab 2 or 3 stories would be there.Now my question is how do I change these stories on a daily basis?

Comment: You mean you want to change **Activity's**?

Comment: The content which is present in stories

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! At StackOverFlow we expect that you have ***tried*** to *slove* your answer first. Is it still dosent work post the code that didint work and the problem. Posts trying to ask for code without you tring something is **off-topic**, plus you dont learn.

Comment: Use `JobScheduler` (or, on older devices, `AlarmManager`) to download fresh content periodically.